# How to add space after border-bottom?

Tags: css

May i know how to add space / padding-bottom after border-bottom?  Sample shown as below.  I dont wish add some objects or make it, just wish to use "h2" only.  For example:

> < h2>h2 header< /h2>
> < p>Next element< /p>

[image]

Comment: Please show us some code.. You should probably use `margin-bottom:`

Comment: Something like this:  < h2>h2 header< /h2> < p>Next element< /p>

Comment: Oic... First time know that can use margin-bottom... Thank you all very much... :)

Answer (score 4):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1vazjyts/)

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom:50px; /* space from border to next element */
  padding-bottom:10px; /* space from element to border */
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
}
```

[CSS box model - Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)

Comment: Thank you very much... :)  First time know margin-bottom, i thought "margin" only

Comment: you can apply margin as margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px; which will mean margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 2px; margin-bottom: 3px; and so on.. while margin: 1px 2px; will implt that margin-top and margin-bottom are 1px while left and right are 2px

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-bottom:` in your css. Like in the code below and in the demo. I have used `50px` as an example.

```
h2 {border-bottom:1px solid grey; margin-bottom:50px;}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r4srhwu5/)**

Comment: Thank you very much... :)  Is this come from CSS 3 ?

Comment: Not that i know off, its cleaner to use `margin: 0 0 50px 0;` instead of `margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:50px; margin-left:0; ` but if you only want to change 1 side you can use `margin-bottom`